# Laravel 4 artisan command not seeing binding

Tags: laravel-4

I created a command called AttachUsers. When I run the command I get

```
Argument 1 passed to AttachPhones::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\\Repositories\\Organizations\\OrganizationRepositoryInterface, none given, called in \/Users\/jonson\/sites\/acme\/app\/start\/artisan.php on line 5 and defined","file":"\/Users\/jonson\/sites\/acme\/app\/commands\/AttachPhones.php","line":30}}
```

I have bound my interface in the repositories service provider file AND it is currently woking in my controllers. My command file is as follows

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use \Acme\Repositories\Organizations\OrganizationRepositoryInterface;

class AttachUsers extends Command {

protected $organizations;

/**
 * The console command name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name = 'acme:attach_users';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Cron command to attach users from import to organizations';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(OrganizationRepositoryInterface $organizations)
{
    $this->organizations = $organizations;

    parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling `Artisan::add(new MyCommand)`. Any time you use the "new" keyword, the IoC container is completely bypassed, and automatic dependency injection will **not** work. Instead, use `Artisan::add(App::make('MyCommand'))` or the shorthand, `Artisan::resolve('MyCommand')`.